# admob plugin not working with cordova and intel XDK in fixed Landscape view

Tags: cordova, admob, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

i follow this tutorial on 
[How To Plugin Admob And How To Plugin Admob In Intel XDK Software Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8d1KOIqBtig) 
[How To Plugin Admob And How To Plugin Admob In Intel XDK Software Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KB8efpAByS0) 
and he is using `com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob` admob plugin 
it worked fine on Portrait view

[image: Portrait]

but the ads not working and showing up on Landscape view

[image: Landscape]

please any help on how to fix this or if there another way to do this 
and show up the ads in Landscape view many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i change the plugin to [AdMob Plugin Pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) and it really is the best and it work fine and they have an example on how to use it in every thing using cordova and an [example](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/test/index.html) on how to start the plugin in the app.
if you would like to activate the real ads just change `isTesting: true` to false and uncomment `bannerId: admobid.banner,` and  `interstitialId: admobid.interstitial,`

```
function initAd(){
    var defaultOptions = {
        // bannerId: admobid.banner,
        // interstitialId: admobid.interstitial,
        // adSize: 'SMART_BANNER',
        // width: integer, // valid when set adSize 'CUSTOM'
        // height: integer, // valid when set adSize 'CUSTOM'
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        // offsetTopBar: false, // avoid overlapped by status bar, for iOS7+
        bgColor: 'black', // color name, or '#RRGGBB'
        // x: integer,      // valid when set position to 0 / POS_XY
        // y: integer,      // valid when set position to 0 / POS_XY
        isTesting: true, // set to true, to receiving test ad for testing purpose
        // autoShow: true // auto show interstitial ad when loaded, set to false if prepare/show
    };
    AdMob.setOptions( defaultOptions );
    registerAdEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there is no inventory? Have you checked the logs on logcat?

I'm using this plugin and it's working fine for me: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova, maybe you could try.